# How do I redirect to a html page and pass variables to that page in Java?

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets

I have a form on my index.html page which makes a POST request to a Java Servlet. This servlet does some processing and I would like to redirect back to index.html with some variables that the servlet has produced.

In PHP, it would be as simple as:

```
header("Location: index.html?var1=a&var2=b");
```

How can I acheive the same with Java, hopefully making use of a GET request.

Thanks all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a Java Servlet, you'll want to write:

```
response.sendRedirect("index.html?var1=a&var2=b...");
```

Oh right, I should note that you'll want to do this in the processor method like doGet() or doPost()...

Answer (score 3):

You redirect the response to the same servlet with some additional values:

```
req.setAttribute("message","Hello world");
rd =req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
```

And in your servlet, you grab the data with:

```
<%=request.getAttribute("message");%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
HttpResponse.sendRedirect("Location: index.html?var1=a&var2=b");
```

See [this link](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as :

```
response.sendRedirect("index.html?var1=a&var2=b");
```